# SMTP Email Validator throws error on non-existent email

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm using the SMTP Validator from Google Code to validate my email. As a test run I enter a non-existent email: [...@crappyCoconuts.com] However, instead of using my `die()` error message, it throws another 2 error messages telling it will not connect and the domain does not exist. **How do I properly check if the email exists or not and return a proper message ?** I know I can simply surpress `error_reporting(0)`, but that will just hide the problem, not solving it.

```
if (preg_match("/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i", $email)) {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();

        $results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email));
        if (!$results[$email]) {
            die("Your email address does not exist");
            $dbh = null;
        }
    } else {
        die("Your email address is in improper format");
        $dbh = null;
    }
} else {

    die("Your email address is in improper format");
    $dbh = null;
}
```

Error Messages:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/u313677887/public_html/smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to crappyCoconuts.com:25 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/u313677887/public_html/smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 154
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either implement a custom error handler using [set_error_handler](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) or you supress the output warning using `@fsockopen()` instead of `fsockopen()`. You can then check what `fsockopen()` has returned.

> fsockopen() returns a file pointer which may be used together with the other file functions (such as fgets(), fgetss(), fwrite(), fclose(), and feof()). If the call fails, it will return FALSE.

False meaning the domain was invalid and thus the e-mail address is invalid.